# Searching through two multidimensional arrays and grouping together similar subarrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to search through two multidimensional arrays to find any elements  in common in a given subarray and then put the results in a third array where the entire subarrays with similar elements are grouped together (not just the similar elements).

The data is imported from two CSVs:

```
require 'csv'
array = CSV.read('primary_csv.csv')
  #=> [["account_num", "account_name", "primary_phone", "second_phone", "status],
  #=>  ["11111",        "John Smith",   "8675309",      "            ", "active"], 
  #=>  ["11112",        "Tina F.",      "5551234",      "5555678"     , "disconnected"],
  #=>  ["11113",        "Troy P.",      "9874321",      "            ", "active"]] 
  # and so on...

second_array = CSV.read('customer_service.csv')
  #=> [["date",   "name",      "agent", "call_length", "phone",   "second_phone", "complaint"],
  #=>  ["3/1/15", "Mary ?",    "Bob X", "5:00",        "5551234", "          ",   "rude"],
  #=>  ["3/2/15", "Mrs. Smith", "Stew", "1:45",        "9995678", "8675309"   ,   "says shes not a customer"]] 
  # and so on...
```

If any number is present as an element in a subarray on both `primary.csv` and `customer_service.csv`, I want that entire subarray (as opposed to just the common elements), put into a third array, `results_array`.  The desire output based upon the above sample is:

```
results_array = [["11111",        "John Smith",   "8675309",      "            ", "active"],
                 ["3/2/15", "Mrs. Smith", "Stew", "1:45",        "9995678", "8675309"   ,   "says shes not a customer"]] # and so on...
```

I then want to export the array into a new CSV, where each subarray is its own row of the CSV.  I intend to iterate over each subarray by joining it with a `,` to make it comma delimited and then put the results into a new CSV:

```
results_array.each do {|j| j.join(",")}
File.open("results.csv", "w") {|f| f.puts results_array}
  #=> 11111,John Smith,8675309, ,active
  #=> 3/2/15,Mrs. Smith,Stew,1:45,9995678,8675309,says shes not a customer 
  # and so on...
```

How can I achieve the desired output?  I am aware that the final product will look messy because similar data (for example, phone number) will be in different columns.  But I need to find a way to generally group the data together.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "put in a "blank" array ..."

Comment: An empty subarray between the groupings.  (Admittedly, a secondary issue to the main problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `a1` and `a2` are the two arrays (excluding header rows).

**Code**

```
def combine(a1, a2)
  h2 = a2.each_with_index
         .with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(arr,i),h|
           arr.each { |e| es = e.strip; h[es] << i if number?(es) } }
  a1.each_with_object([]) do |arr, b|
    d = arr.each_with_object([]) do |str, d|
      s = str.strip    
      d.concat(a2.values_at(*h2[s])) if number?(s) && h2.key?(s)
    end
    b << d.uniq.unshift(arr) if d.any?
  end
end

def number?(str)
  str =~ /^\d+$/
end
```

**Example**

Here is your example, modified somewhat:

```
a1 = [
  ["11111", "John Smith", "8675309", "",        "active"      ], 
  ["11112", "Tina F.",    "5551234", "5555678", "disconnected"],
  ["11113", "Troy P.",    "9874321", "",        "active"      ]
] 

a2 = [
  ["3/1/15", "Mary ?",     "Bob X", "5:00", "5551234", "",        "rude"],
  ["3/2/15", "Mrs. Smith", "Stew",  "1:45", "9995678", "8675309", "surly"],
  ["3/7/15", "Cher",       "Sonny", "7:45", "9874321", "8675309", "Hey Jude"]
]

combine(a1, a2)
  #=> [[["11111",   "John Smith", "8675309",       "",
  #      "active"],
  #     ["3/2/15",  "Mrs. Smith", "Stew",          "1:45",
  #      "9995678", "8675309",    "surly"],
  #     ["3/7/15",  "Cher",       "Sonny",         "7:45",
  #      "9874321", "8675309",    "Hey Jude"]
  #    ],
  #    [["11112",   "Tina F.",    "5551234",       "5555678",
  #      "disconnected"],
  #     ["3/1/15",  "Mary ?",     "Bob X",         "5:00",
  #      "5551234", "",           "rude"]
  #    ],
  #    [["11113",   "Troy P.",    "9874321",       "",
  #      "active"],
  #     ["3/7/15",  "Cher",       "Sonny",         "7:45",
  #      "9874321", "8675309",    "Hey Jude"]
  #    ]
  #  ]
```

**Explanation**

First, we define a helper:

```
def number?(str)
  str =~ /^\d+$/
end
```

For example:

```
number?("8675309") #=> 0 ("truthy)
number?("3/1/15")  #=> nil
```

Now index `a2` on the values that represent numbers:

```
h2 = a2.each_with_index
       .with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(arr,i),h|
         arr.each { |e| es = e.strip; h[es] << i if number?(es) } }
  #=> {"5551234"=>[0], "9995678"=>[1], "8675309"=>[1, 2], "9874321"=>[2]}
```

This says, for example, that the "numeric" field "8675309" is contained in elements at offsets 1 and 2 of `a2` (i.e, for Mrs. Smith and Cher).

We can now simply run through the elements of `a1` looking for matches.

The code:

```
arr.each_with_object([]) do |str, d|
  s = str.strip    
  d.concat(a2.values_at(*h2[s])) if number?(s) && h2.key?(s)
end
```

steps through the elements of `arr`, assigning each to the block variable `str`.  For example, if `arr` holds the first element of `a1` `str` will in turn equals `"11111"`, `"John Smith"`, and so on. After `s = str.strip`, this says that if a `s` has a numerical representation and there is a matching key in `h2`, the (initially empty) array `d` is concatenated with the elements of `a2` given by the value of `h2[s]`.

After completing this loop we see if `d` contains any elements of `a2`:

```
b << d.uniq.unshift(arr) if d.any?
```

If it does, we remove duplicates, prepend the array with `arr` and save it to `b`.

Note that this allows one element of `a2` to match multiple elements of `a1`.